# PHP Passing arguments in a user defined function into $_POST()

Tags: php

I'm creating a function for PHP form validation. The idea is that if a user has not filled out a required field (for example, if a `$_POST` variable called "name" is empty), then the user will be warned.

This function doesn't seem to work, however:

```
function addError($x) {
    if (!$_POST["$x"]) {
        $error.="Please enter your $x";
    }
}

echo $error;
```

I've isolated the problem down to the passing of the argument `$x` into `$_POST`, i.e. this line:

```
if (!$_POST["$x"]) {
```

Specifically, `$_POST["$x"]`. Is this the right way/syntax to pass an argument?

Thank you!

Comment: `$error` will be out of the `scope`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be like -

```
$error = '';
function addError($x, $error) {
    if (!$x) { // Check for the data
        $error.="Please enter your $x"; // Concatenate the errors
    }
    return $error; // return the error
}

echo addError($_POST[$x], $error); // Pass the data to check & the error variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `$error` a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php
$x=$_POST["name"];
function addError($x) 
{
    if ($x==null)
    {
        $error="Please enter your name";
    }
    else
    {
        $error='';
    }
    return $error;
}
echo addError($x);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$error = "";
function addError($x) 
{
   global $error;
   if ("" == $_POST['"'.$x.'"']) 
   {
      $error.="Please enter your".$x;
   }
}
addError("name");
echo $error;
```

Answer (score 0):

I referenced above two answers and write some code for this question. It works when I tested. You might get some idea for your coding.
Here is my tested code.

***PHP section***

```
<?php 
        function check_error($x){
            $error = "";
            if(isset($_POST[$x]) && $_POST[$x] == ""){
                $error = "Please Enter Data";           
            }       
            return $error;  
        }

        echo check_error('txt_name');   

?>
```

***HTML section***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Testing </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Testing </h1>
    <hr/>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="txt_name" value="" placeholder="Your name" />
        <input type="Submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```